# Is there a way to get push to scroll functionality in Windows 8 metro Apps?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

In the Windows 8 Consumer Preview, moving the mouse towards the left or right edge in the start screen causes the content to scroll.

The standard controls (and currently released preview apps) does not seem to support this.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I noticed that even in the demo apps this function is not there yet.  I hope they add it as a default, it would make sense.  Mouse/touch compatibility is still not 100% IMHO.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to repro this? Thanks. Holding left key on my mouse on Start Menu doesn't cause anything to scroll for me.

Comment: If you move your mouse on the start screen towards the left/right edge of the screen, it will start scrolling - you don't need to press any keys. The speed of the scrolling depends on the speed with which you move towards the edge. This does not work in any of the preview apps or the default controls. This feels very inconsistent to me, you sort of expect all such controls (as that on the start screen) to operate in the same way across the metro part of windows 8.

Comment: I think I had to click first before I could do it - perhaps to set focus? Seems like it detects mouse movement even if the cursor can't move beyond the edge of the screen. I think you could do that with DirectX...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question at TechEd North America this year, after one of the sessions given by [Paul Gusmorino](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Speakers/paul+gusmorino), a lead program manager for the UI platform.

His answer was that no, apps can't do push-against-the-edge-to-scroll. WinJS and WinRT/XAML apps don't even get the events you would need to implement it yourself. Apps get events at the level of the mouse *pointer,* and once the mouse pointer hits the edge of the screen, it can't move any farther and you don't get any more events. (Well, it might wiggle up and down a little bit, but not if it hit a corner. At any rate, it's not good enough to scroll the way the Start screen does.)

He mentioned that, if you were writing a C++/DirectX app, you would be able to get the raw mouse input you needed to do this yourself -- you can get low-level "device moved by DX,DY" rather than the high-level "pointer moved to X,Y". I'm guessing this is how the Start screen does it, though I didn't think to ask.

But no, it's not built-in, it's not something you can implement yourself (unless you write your app in low-level C++/DirectX), and it sounds like they have no plans to add it before Windows 8 ships.

Personally, I think it's pretty short-sighted of them to have apps feel cripped compared to the Start screen, but evidently they're not concerned about little things like usability. `</rant>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to get information on mouse moving beyond the screen and use the delta information to scroll your content.

```cs
using Windows.Devices.Input;

var mouse = MouseDevice.GetForCurrentView();
mouse.MouseMoved += mouse_MouseMoved;

private void mouse_MouseMoved(MouseDevice sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{
    tb.Text = args.MouseDelta.X.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Sure you can something like this, but as this works natively in the windows 8 start menu, it would be natural that the standard controls support this directly. Anyways, thanks for answering.