# Scroll the scrollviewer with mouse at the end of the screen like the Windows Start menu

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to get push to scroll functionality in Windows 8 metro Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579343/is-there-a-way-to-get-push-to-scroll-functionality-in-windows-8-metro-apps)

The new Windows 8 Start menu scrolls horizontally when the mouse cursor reaches the end of the screen.

How can I make a scrollviewer works the same way?

```
<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}">
 ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Found the solution here: http://www.familie-smits.com/post/2012/08/22/Door-het-GridView-met-de-muis-scrollen.aspx